# Devise CanCan cannot create User via Post when using Curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I've followed Tony Amoyal's guide [Rails Authentication with Devise and CanCan part 2 – Restful Resources for Administrators](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/09/29/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-part-2-restful-resources-for-administrators/) and created the User controller.

I've got token based authentication enabled and CanCan is setup to allow access to only admins to do anything useful.

Code snippets of note are

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :ensure_authentication_token

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :token_authenticatable

  attr_accessible :company_name, :role, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  ROLES = %w[admin customer]  
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_user, :only => [:index,:new,:edit]
  load_and_authorize_resource

  ...
end

class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new # guest user

      if user.role == "admin"      
        can :manage, :all
      elsif user.role == "customer"
        can :address, :lookup
        cannot [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy, :index], [User]
        can [:show], [User], :id => user.id
      end
    end    
end
```

Now when I use curl to make GET, PUT & DELETE requests it works fine. Notice the auth_token param (it is admin user's token)

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://localhost:3000/users.json?auth_token=Z6Sgkd65w1oCWckpNrdya54FkHy6sMgWLn1BNno7wa9xSEi0xvoxfrRD4Y8z -i
```

POST requests don't seem to work and get redirected which suggests authentication did not kick in using the provided token.

Post request:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://localhost:3000/users -d '{"auth_token":"Z6Sgkd65w1oCWckpNrdya54FkHy6sMgWLn1BNno7wa9xSEi0xvoxfrRD4Y8z", "user":{"company_name":"Test","role":"customer","password":"XXXXXXXX","password_confirmation":"XXXXXXXX","email":"test8@test.com"}}' -i
```

Dev log:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Jan 07 18:54:27 +1100 2011
  Processing by UsersController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"Z6Sgkd65w1oCWckpNrdya54FkHy6sMgWLn1BNno7wa9xSEi0xvoxfrRD4Y8z", "user"=>{"company_name"=>"Test", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "role"=>"customer", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"test8@test.com"}}
Completed   in 88ms
Redirected to https://localhost:3000/
```

Is the use of Curl incorrect? or 
Do I need to login first and then set the session in the cookie in the POST request? or 
Am I doing some silly monkies?

Am fairly new to Rails & Ruby so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your controller:

```
# disable csrf protection for the controller: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

This is telling the controller not to check the form authenticity token that Rails is expecting when receiving a POST.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I cannot verify the answer because we decided to use Sinatra for the above project for various reasons.